# Hadoop YARN setup authentication issue

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I follow the instruction of this page to install single machine yarn cluster http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.5-alpha/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

But when I run the example jar, the job hang there and I check the log of resource manager, find the following error (the first is client side log, the second is resource manager log )

**(Client side)**

```
13/10/18 17:30:36 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:zhangj82 (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException
java.io.IOException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getJobStatus(ClientServiceDelegate.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getJobStatus(YARNRunner.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$1.run(Job.java:313)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$1.run(Job.java:310)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.updateStatus(Job.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.isComplete(Job.java:594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.monitorAndPrintJob(Job.java:1277)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.RandomWriter.run(RandomWriter.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.RandomWriter.main(RandomWriter.java:294)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

**Resource Manager**

```
2013-10-18 17:35:26,128 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8040: readAndProcess threw exception javax.security.sasl.SaslException: DIGEST-MD5: IO error acquiring password [Caused by org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken: Can't de-serialize tokenIdentifier] from client 127.0.0.1. Count of bytes read: 0
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: DIGEST-MD5: IO error acquiring password [Caused by org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken: Can't de-serialize tokenIdentifier]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.digest.DigestMD5Server.validateClientResponse(DigestMD5Server.java:594)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.digest.DigestMD5Server.evaluateResponse(DigestMD5Server.java:244)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Connection.saslReadAndProcess(Server.java:1173)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Connection.readAndProcess(Server.java:1350)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.doRead(Server.java:726)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.doRunLoop(Server.java:525)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.run(Server.java:500)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken: Can't de-serialize tokenIdentifier
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcServer.getIdentifier(SaslRpcServer.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcServer$SaslDigestCallbackHandler.handle(SaslRpcServer.java:217)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.digest.DigestMD5Server.validateClientResponse(DigestMD5Server.java:585)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.readFields(Text.java:306)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenIdentifier.readFields(AbstractDelegationTokenIdentifier.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcServer.getIdentifier(SaslRpcServer.java:109)
        ... 8 more
2013-10-18 17:35:26,308 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_1382088798449_0001_01_000001 Container Transitioned from ACQUIRED to RUNNING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug been raised in [Hadoop issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-4406). Basically to overcome this you may apply source level patch as described in [BlockTokenSecretManager](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12564901/BlockTokenSecretManager.patch) or try to update to latest version of Hadoop